# Using LogManager.GetLogger with Unity

Tags: log4net, unity-container

Given this class:

```
class Foo
{
    readonly ILog log;

    public Foo(ILog log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    } 

    ...
}
```

I'd like to configure Unity to inject ILog. That's easy:

```
container.RegisterInstance<ILog>(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(XYZ)));
```

But I'd like to make Unity call `LogManager.GetLogger` with the type of the parent type being resolved.

This is close:

```
container.RegisterType<ILog>(new InjectionFactory((c, t, s) => LogManager.GetLogger(t)));
```

But `t` in this case is the type being resolved (`ILog`), not the type that the object is being resolved for (`Foo`).

I know I can do this:

```
container.RegisterType<Foo>(new InjectionFactory(c => new Foo(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Foo)));
```

But I don't want to have to add that crazy declaration every time I register an object.

I know this can be done in Autofac, and I know the Real Answer is not to use Unity in the first place, but can this be done? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity might not give you all the goodies some of the other containers offer but I have yet to find a feature you can't easily add.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<TrackingExtension>();
container.RegisterType<ILog>(
  new InjectionFactory((ctr, type, name) =>
    {
      var tracker = ctr.Resolve<ITracker>();
      var parentType = tracker.CurrentBuildNode.Parent.BuildKey.Type;
      return LogManager.GetLogger(parentType);
    }));
var sut = container.Resolve<UsesLog>();
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(UsesLog), sut.Log.Type);
```

You can find the source code for the *TrackingExtension* [here](http://tecx.codeplex.com). Its located in the *TecX.Unity* project folder.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with something based on the same model. One thing I found is that I had to implement IRecovery to handle cases where PostBuildUp wasn't called.

Comment: _PostBuildUp_ of the _TrackingStrategy_ did not get called? As far as I know this is only possible if either the strategy declares the build-up as complete in _PreBuildUp_ (which it does not) or if there is an exception somewhere in the pipeline which prematurely interupts the chain.

Comment: that's right. I'm not sure if there were exceptions but we do have some [OptionalDependencies] that might not be able to be loaded, so there is nothing to *PostBuildUp*.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a DI container to return you a logger based on the class’ type information, then put the type information into the public interface so the DI container can see it. It removes the need for any container specific override features and then it won’t matter if you are using Unity or AutoFac.

Someone that knows the log4net object model well might be able to give you a more efficient implementation, but try something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnityLoging
{
    public interface ILog<T> : log4net.ILog
    { }

    public class MyLogger<T> : log4net.Core.LogImpl, ILog<T>
    {
        public MyLogger() : base(log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T).Name).Logger)
        { }
    }

    public class ClassToLog
    {
        private readonly log4net.ILog log;

        public ClassToLog(ILog<ClassToLog> log)
        {
            this.log = log;
        }

        public void LogMe()
        {
            log.Debug("Got here");
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GenericLogRegistrationTest()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType(typeof(ILog<>), typeof(MyLogger<>));

            ClassToLog c = container.Resolve<ClassToLog>();
            c.LogMe();

            log4net.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It's container agnostic but a bit verbose and a developer needs to know that the _T_ in _ILog<T>_ must match the type of the class that has the logger as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a very clean approach: https://github.com/roblevine/UnityLoggingExtensions