# How would I do the following NInject registration with Unity IoC?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ninject

I want to be able to do the following type registration with unity, does anyone know how?

```
 Bind<ILogger>().To<AssemblyEditorLogger>()
   .WithConstructorArgument("currentClassName",
                            x => x.Request.ParentContext != null ? 
                            x.Request.ParentContext.Request.Service.FullName : typeof (BootStrapper).FullName);
```

Basically in Unity how do I get access to the type of class we are creating the instance for - I am using constructor injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576842/using-logmanager-getlogger-with-unity/8586105#8586105).

You can get access to the type the same way it is done for `LogManager.GetLogger()`.